# Modularization in Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to learn how modularization works in Android. I am using Kotlin DSL.

In each build.gradle.kts file, do I have to add default config such as minSdk, target SDK etc? In other words, can I only set configuration in for example app module build.gradle.kts file and in other modules for example for features, can I only declare dependencies?

NowInAndroid app has following code for build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("nowinandroid.android.feature")
    id("nowinandroid.android.library.compose")
    id("nowinandroid.android.library.jacoco")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.google.samples.apps.nowinandroid.feature.bookmarks"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material3.windowSizeClass)
}
```

which only declares dependencies and plugins, but I suppose that in those plugins there are different configurations.

The other method I saw was to inherit from other build.gradle file by using

```
apply {
 (path to build.gradle) file
}
```

But with using that method I can't declare namespace, therefore I have to add this in build.gradle file, which is shared across different features and without it I can't access resources in given feature module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build logic in a multi-project build can be organized into reusable plugins (Gradle Convention Plugins).
Convention plugin does not refer to a specific plugin (like com.android.library), but rather to a class of precompiled plugins whose role is to extract some of the shared build logic.

First, let's manually create a new module call `build-logic` with the following structure:

```
rootProject
├─build-logic
│  │  settings.gradle.kts
│  └─convention
│      │  build.gradle.kts
│      └─src
│          └─main
│              └─kotlin
│                    AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin.kt
├─...
```

We will include the `build-logic` module in the root Project with Composing builds.

> A composite build is simply a build that includes other builds. In many ways a composite build is similar to a Gradle multi-project build, except that instead of including single projects, complete builds are included.

**`rootProject/settings.gradle.kts`**:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("build-logic") // include build-logic module
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "GradleConventionPluginsSample"
include(":app")
```

> A build that is included in a composite build is referred to, naturally enough, as an "included build". Included builds do not share any configuration with the composite build, or the other included builds. Each included build is configured and executed in isolation.

Since the included build is completely independent, we need to declare the repository source in `settings.gradle.kts`, and also explicitly declare the path of version catalogs file.

**`rootProject/build-logic/settings.gradle.kts`**:

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            // make sure the file rootProject/gradle/verison.toml exists!
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "build-logic"
include(":convention")
```

Note that you need to ensure that the file rootProject/gradle/verison.toml exists, and add the following lines to it.

**`rootProject/gradle/verison.toml`**:

```ini
[versions]
...
androidGradlePlugin = "8.1.2"
kotlin = "1.9.10"


[libraries]
...
# Dependencies of the included build-logic
android-gradlePlugin = { group = "com.android.tools.build", name = "gradle", version.ref = "androidGradlePlugin" }
kotlin-gradlePlugin = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlin" }

[plugins]
...
```

**`rootProject/build-logic/convention/build.gradle.kts`**:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

group = "com.bqliang.gradleconventionplugins.buildlogic"

// Configure the build-logic plugins to target JDK 17
// This matches the JDK used to build the project, and is not related to what is running on device.
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(libs.android.gradlePlugin)
    compileOnly(libs.kotlin.gradlePlugin)
}

gradlePlugin {
    // register the convention plugin
    plugins {
        register("androidLibrary") {
            id = "bqliang.android.library"
            implementationClass = "AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

In the file of `build-logic/convention/build.gradle.kts`, We apply `kotlin-dsl` plugin, add dependencies... and finally register the convention plugin.

Note that we haven't implemented the implementationClass yet, this is our final step.

Put shared build logic in `AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin` so that we can reuse it in other Android Library modules.

**`rootProject/build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin.kt`**:

```kotlin
import com.android.build.api.dsl.CommonExtension
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension
import org.gradle.api.JavaVersion
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.configure
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.withType
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

class AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        with(project) {
            with(pluginManager) {
                apply("com.android.library")
                apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
            }

            extensions.configure<LibraryExtension> {
                configureKotlinAndroid(this)
                defaultConfig.targetSdk = 34
            }
        }
    }

    private fun Project.configureKotlinAndroid(
        commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *, *>,
    ) {
        commonExtension.apply {
            compileSdk = 34

            defaultConfig {
                minSdk = 26
            }

            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
                targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            }
        }

        configureKotlin()
    }

    private fun Project.configureKotlin() {
        // Use withType to workaround https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55947
        tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
            kotlinOptions {
                // Set JVM target to 11
                jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> My Gradle version is 8.4, if you can't find some classes in the above code, you can try to upgrade your Gradle version first.
> **`rootProject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`**:
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip

Since we're already using the Version Catalog. Why not put the plugin id of AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin we just created in `libs.versions.toml` file?

**`rootProject/gralde/libs.versions.toml`**:

```ini
[versions]
...

[libraries]
...

[plugins]
bqliang-android-library = { id = "bqliang.android.library", version = "unspecified" }
...
```

Now we can use the AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin in other android library modules. Create a new Android library module called `mylibrary` by Android Studio. The build.gradle.kts in `mylibrary` module is as follows:

```kotlin
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.bqliang.mylibrary"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

We have put the above build logic about Android Library in `AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin`, so we can remove them and just apply our convention plugin.

```kotlin
plugins {
    // just apply out convention plugin simply here
    alias(libs.plugins.bqliang.android.library)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.bqliang.mylibrary"

    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Great! We have created a reusable convention plugin that shares build logic across multiple projects. In this way, we can abstract the same build logic(like compileSdk, sourceCompatibility, targetCompatibility...) from different modules. As far as I know, Now in Android project also use this way.

The above is just a very simple example, actually you can share more build logic in the convention plugin, like productFlavors, Jetpack Compose, Room, build type, test, etc.

These plugins are additive and composable, and try to **only accomplish a single responsibility**. Modules can then pick and choose the configurations they need.

References:

- [Using Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html)
- [Now in Android - build-logic](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/build-logic/README.md)
- [Gradle Composing builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)
- [Sharing build logic between subprojects Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html)
- [Sharing convention plugins with build logic build Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_sharing_convention_plugins_with_build_logic.html)
- [Developing Custom Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html)
- [Use buildSrc to abstract imperative logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources)
- [Unlocking Reusability in Gradle: How to Use Kotlin-written Convention Plugins](https://medium.com/@amsavarthan/unlocking-reusability-in-gradle-how-to-use-kotlin-written-convention-plugins-11b95cb008ef)

Comment: I did all this but when I sync Gradle in the consuming module's `build.gradle.kts` file I get error:

```
e: file:///.../app/build.gradle.kts:53:25: Unresolved reference: androidx
```

`androidx` here referring to the first entry in the `dependencies` block in this `build.gradle` file, like:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    ...
}
```

Note that I mentioned I implemented the entire process as described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77278238/2077405) & have cross-checked the implementation for typos or omissions several times over.

Comment: Never mind, just found out that naming the [extension property](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/5f5bd91a686a414007c9ce3c7acb26d2b0bd293a/build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/ProjectExtensions.kt#L24C13-L24C17), "`libs`", declared in Gradle Convention plugin build config module seem to collide with the ` PluginDependenciesSpecScope.libs` property in the `build.gradle.kts` of other modules.

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes you need to apply minSdk, target SDK.

You can create a generic build.gradle file for all your android 
library modules and extend from it in all your android library 
modules

Note Do not create .kts file for generic gradle file or else you 
will not be able to extend from it.

Extend by writing this notation

apply {
from("$rootDir/android-library-build.gradle")
}


dependencies {
 // Put module specific dependencies here...
}
```

Comment: That's really good advice from you. Do you know how do I specify namespace for build.gradle.kts files that inherit from this generic build.gradle file? Is it even possible? I suppose it is based on what developers did in NowInAndroid app, but I can't reproduce it

Comment: No i don't have any idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

> can I only set configuration in for example app module build.gradle.kts file and in other modules for example for features, can I only declare dependencies?

Yes you can.
in Project view, create a new file name exp: common-android-build.gradle, and put the default values that you want, exp:

```
//apply plugin: "com.android.library" <- This wont work, you need to declare it in the build.gradle on every module
//apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" <- This will work

android {
    compileSdk = libs.versions.compileSdk.get().toInteger()

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInteger()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInteger()
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(1.8)
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
}
```

Sync & Build your project, now in your module gradle:

```
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION")
plugins {
  alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
  alias(libs.plugins.kotlin)
// ...
}

apply(from="../../common-android-build.gradle") // Depending on you module depth add/remove "../"

android {
  namespace = "earth.core.data" // Only namespace is required
}

dependencies {
// More dependencies ... 
 }
```

Wondering about the "alias" & "libs"? here a good tutorial on [How To Manage Dependencies/Plugins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnlBe-OJXtU) (used in NIA!)